# Open File Dialog ... Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, application-settings

I am trying to use the openFileDialog, it was working up until this morning when I made what I thought was a simple change....

I changed the Filter and Initial Directory properties from hardcoded strings to application settings and this is where the error comes in. From what I can tell everything should be fine... Ill post the new and old code....

**NEW CODE**

```
    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofDialog.Filter = Properties.Settings.Default.openFileFilter;
        ofDialog.FilterIndex = 3;
        ofDialog.Multiselect = false;
        ofDialog.InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.openFileInitialDirectory;

        bool? fileSelected = ofDialog.ShowDialog();

        if(fileSelected == true)
        {
            selectedFileTxtBx.Text = ofDialog.FileName;
        }
```

**Application Settings**

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.openFileFilter; = Exe (.exe)|*.exe|MSI (.msi)|*.msi| All (*.*)|*.*
 Properties.Settings.Default.openFileInitialDirectory; = \\\\UNC\\PATH
```

**Old Code**

```
    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofDialog.Filter = "Exe (.exe)|*.exe|MSI (.msi)|*.msi| All (*.*)|*.*";
        ofDialog.FilterIndex = 3;
        ofDialog.Multiselect = false;
        ofDialog.InitialDirectory = "\\\\UNC\\PATH";

        bool? fileSelected = ofDialog.ShowDialog();

        if(fileSelected == true)
        {
            selectedFileTxtBx.Text = ofDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory serves correctly, `Properties.Settings.Default.openFileInitialDirectory` should actually just be set to `\\UNC\PATH`, as the string will already be escaped.

Comment: That seems to be it, can you answer another question then, I also have a regex in there can you confirm how that will work....... `^\\\\UNC\\PATH\\.*`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how that regex will work. All I can suggest is try it, either in a debug session or via some sort of regex tester. I've actually found this site to be quite handy whenever I've needed to do any regex work (which is very infrequent): http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html